# Creating a set of indicators based on the sequential occurrence of a number in a vector of integers

Tags: r

Let's say that I have a vector of integers

```
x <- c(10, 1, 1, 4, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7)
```

and I want to create two sets of indicators based on this vector. The first indicator , `y`, should be equal to `1` as long as `x == 10` and then equal to zero for the rest of the vector. Importantly, it has to ignore any additional `10` found later in the vector. For example, given `x` above, I would expect

```
y <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

and if

```
x <- c(10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 5, 10, 7, 9)
```

then

```
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

The second indicator, `z` should be equal to `1` for the first element after the sequence has ended. Given the `x` vectors above, I would expect the outputs to be:

```
z <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
z <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Using one vector to work out the other is perfectly fine. I haven't been able to find a neat way of solving this given that the number used to work out the sequence can occur later in the vector, so a simple check for equality doesn't work in my case.

Comment: What would be your `y` when `x` is `x <- c(1, 10, 10, 1, 4, 10, 10, 7, 7, 7)` i.e `x` does not start with 10?

Comment: In that case it should return `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. It looks like @akrun's solution below also correctly captures that edge case, even though that would not occur in the particular setting in which I am applying this. Good point, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rle` to change the values that are not equal to the first set of 10 to 0 by assigning those 'values' to FALSE

```
+(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x == 10), values[seq_along(values) > 1] <- FALSE)))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
+(inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x == 10), values[seq_along(values) > 1] <- FALSE)))
#[1] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

for the second case, get the position with `which` and create a logical vector with `%in%`

```
library(data.table)
+( seq_along(x) %in% which(rleid(x == 10) > 1)[1])
#[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 +( seq_along(x) %in% which(rleid(x == 10) > 1)[1])
#[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Was unaware of `rle`. Works really well for this case.